# Why the segment vilation for this code

Tags: c++, linux, memory, segmentation-fault

I'm working on CentOS 6.5 64-bit.  The program I'm running is compiled with GCC (G++ really) 4.4.7.  When this is compiled for 32-bits, all works fine (through this point anyway).  Here's the code (which just arranges for a SCSI Write16 command):

```
void Write16::BuildCommand(UInt32 numSectors, UInt32 bz) {
    buffSize_ = numSectors * bz;
    if(pBuff_) {
        delete [] reinterpret_cast<UInt8*>(pBuff_);
        pBuff_ = NULL;
    }

    if(!pBuff_) pBuff_ = new UInt8[buffSize_];  // **Causes SEGV in 64-bits**
    if(!pCdb_) pCdb_ = new UInt8[cdbLen16];

    ::memset(pCdb_, 0, cdbLen16);

    FillRandom(pBuff_, buffSize_);

    // code continues to set LBA and number of sectors
}
```

When execution reaches the line I've commented above, when compiled for 64-bits, I get the segmentation violation.  Write16::BuildCommand is called with numSectors = 1400 and bz = 512; thus buffSize_ == 716800.  Clearly, 716800 bytes is peanuts from the heap (this system has 8gb of physical memory).

I thought that it might have something to do with user limitations.  Here's the output from ulimit -a:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 60209
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 32768
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1024
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

I've upped my stack size to 32mb (it was 16 if I recall correctly).  However, my max memory is unlimited and so is virtual memory.  At this point, I'm stumped and would like a second set of eyes.

---

**EDIT**
I've found the problem with the code.  The issue was with the FillRandom() function.  This function used the random() library call.  I noticed the return of this function is of type *long int*.  My fatal assumption was that the long int was always 4 bytes wide.  The filled the incoming array like this:

```
void FillRandom(const void *pBuff, UInt32 size) {
    // size is in bytes, convert to integer sized quantities
    UInt32 numLongIntObjs = size / sizeof(long int); // if the area isn't quite divisible, oh well
    long int * pTemp = reinterpret_cast<long int*>(const_cast<void*>(pBuff));

    for(UInt32 i = 0; i < numLongIntObjs; i++) {
        *pTemp = random();
        pTemp++;
    }
}
```

Well, originally, the code looked more like this:

```
void FillRandom(const void *pBuff, UInt32 size) {
    // size is in bytes, convert to integer sized quantities
    UInt32 numDwordObjs = size / 4; // *** OH NO, not good ***
    long int * pTemp = reinterpret_cast<long int*>(const_cast<void*>(pBuff));

    for(UInt32 i = 0; i < numDwordObjs; i++) {
        *pTemp = random();
        pTemp++;
    }
}
```

Rather than answer my own question.  I'm going to edit this way and cleanly mark it closed.

Incidentally, I inadvertently found this by running the code through valgrind.  Valgrind didn't find the issue.  In fact, Valgrind said it had it's own problems and wanted to submit a bug report.  However, one of the statements it made about a bad 4 byte write, long before the code I identified as causing the SEGV, caught my attention and led me here.

---

**EDIT 2**
Interesting, closing the question isn't what I thought.  Oh well.  I'll leave this here for a few days, perhaps a week, so that people who hit this on searches will see the resolution.  Then, I'll delete.

Comment: Is pBuff_ initialized to NULL when the object is constructed?

Comment: Why do you have the `reinterpret_cast<UInt8*>`?

Comment: What is `pBuff_` type?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson yes, the buffer is initialized to NULL by the ctor of the object.  Also, I know it's null because the problem happens when that conditional is reached and the memory is allocated: gdb shows as much from post-mortem of core file.

Comment: @VadimProzorov the type of pBuff_ is void*.

Comment: @FredLarson the reinterpret_cast is there because pBuff_ is void pointer.

Comment: So why is it a void pointer? Can it point to other types?